# Why does my JTable redraw get a stack overflow when I select the first row?

Tags: java, swing

So I am trying to write a UI in swing. In short, I have a JTable where I listen for selection events, and after a user selects an item, the code takes a bit of a path through the program's code, after which it invokes a table "redraw"; it empties the table, and adds the rows again.

This process seems to work fine for clicking on rows 2-4 (see code bit below), but when I click on the first row, I get a stack overflow I can not explain.

I know it isn't exactly the best solution, as the table practically does not require a redraw, but I would first of all like to keep my code clean and logically structured (which is what causes the redraw), and second I have been trying to get what causes this so long that I would really just like to know what happens.

Here is a runnable class that reproduces the problem:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Tester implements ListSelectionListener {
private DefaultTableModel model;

public Tester(DefaultTableModel model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JTable table = new JTable();
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    table.setModel(model);
    table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new Tester(model));
    model.setColumnCount(3);
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[]{"col1", "col2", "col3"});
    frame.add(table);

    model.addRow(new Object[]{"1", "2", "3"});
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"4", "2", "3"});
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"3", "2", "3"});
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"2", "2", "3"});
}

public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
    model.setRowCount(0);
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"1", "2", "3"});
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"4", "2", "3"});
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"3", "2", "3"});
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"2", "2", "3"});
}
}
```

Comment: +1 for the code which makes it easy to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the stackoverflow is that when you remove all rows and start adding rows you trigger the listener again. I am not a big fan of changing the model in a selection listener (think of the situation where another selection listener is attached to the table ... it will receive completely screwed up events. Possible solution for this is to at least use an `invokeLater` call).

But to avoid your stackoverflow exception, use

```
  @Override
  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
    ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel = ( ListSelectionModel ) event.getSource();
    listSelectionModel.removeListSelectionListener( this );
    model.setRowCount(0);
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"1", "2", "3"});
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"4", "2", "3"});
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"3", "2", "3"});
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"2", "2", "3"});
    listSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener( this );
  }
```

Comment: plus you want to check against isAdjusting :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: I was already doing that, but it would hop between two values for some reason, still giving the stack overflow. It works now, though. Thanks for the help!